# Grouping files by similar name into folders

Tags: python

I am trying to group dataset into folders by name

My file directory looks like this

```
|-images
  |Aaron_Eckhart_0001
  |Aaron_Eckhart_0002
  |Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0001
  |Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0002
  |Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0003
```

And I would like to group the files into a directory that looks like this

```
|-images
  |-Aaron_Eckhart
    |Aaron_Eckhart_0001
    |Aaron_Eckhart_0002
  |-Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim
    |Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0001
    |Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0002
    |Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0003
```

The biggest issue I am facing is when I do the split command, sometimes it will return an array of size 3, and sometimes it will return an array of size 4, therefore, rendering my last command useless when it comes to comparison

```
import os

dir = "img"


for name in os.listdir(dir):
    dir_path = os.path.join(dir, name)
    folder_name = name.split("_")
    person_name = folder_name[0] + "_" +folder_name[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use all the parts but the last:

```py
import os

dir = "img"


for name in os.listdir(dir):
    dir_path = os.path.join(dir, name)
    folder_name = name.split("_")
    person_name = "_".join(folder_name[:-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

`str.rsplit` takes a number parameter that makes for easy splitting:

```py
for name in os.listdir('img'):
    # only the last _ will be split
    folder, file = name.rsplit('_', 1)

    os.makedirs(os.path.join('img', folder), exist_ok=True)
    
    # put your files in that directory
```

Where `'Aaron_Eckhart_0001'.rsplit('_', 1)` gives:

```py
['Aaron_Eckhart', '0001']
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tomer I came up with this solution

```
import os
import shutil

dir = "images"


for name in os.listdir(dir):
    dir_path = os.path.join(dir, name)
    folder_name = name.split("_")
    person_name = "_".join(folder_name[:-1])

    person_name_path = "grouped_imgs" + person_name
    if folder_name[-1] == "0001.jpg":
        os.mkdir(person_name)
        shutil.move(dir_path, person_name)
        print("Folder created: " + dir_path)
    else:
        shutil.move(dir_path, person_name)
```

Comment: Note that the order of files in os.listdir isn't necessarily sorted, so you might have the 0001.jpg file appear last.

Comment: If Tomer's answer was the most useful, please consider accepting it

Comment: @Tomer I had definitely not considered this option but it seems like all the images are grouped as i needed them

Answer (score 0):

If your filenames always end with `_number` then you might harness `.rstrip` method of str following way:

```
names = ["Aaron_Eckhart_0001","Aaron_Eckhart_0002","Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0001","Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0002","Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0003"]
for name in names:
    person_name = name.rstrip('_0123456789')
    print(person_name)
```

Output

```
Aaron_Eckhart
Aaron_Eckhart
Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim
Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim
Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim
```

Explanation: rstrip removes trailing characters, given in argument it accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import itertools

images = ['Aaron_Eckhart_0001', 'Aaron_Eckhart_0002',
          'Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0001', 'Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0002', 'Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0003']

print([
    {k: list(v)}
    for k, v in itertools.groupby(images, lambda x : "_".join(x.split("_")[:-1]))
])
```

---

```
[{'Aaron_Eckhart': ['Aaron_Eckhart_0001', 'Aaron_Eckhart_0002']}, 
 {'Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim': ['Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0001', 'Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0002', 'Abdel_Aziz_Al-Hakim_0003']}]
```